# De mas cercana a lejana desde mi posición, ordenar paginado una lista de localizaciones

Tags: nodejs, typescript, ionic, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy intentando desarrollar una aplicación pero necesito saber de todos los elementos de la base de datos, saber cuales son de todos lo elementos dada una posición sea una calle o coordenadas, cuales son los que están mas cerca de mi en ese momento.
Y que seria mejor una base de datos relacional sql o oracle o no relacional mongo y si, existe alguna forma de hacer la consulta a la la base de datos y que esta ya te devuelva esos datos ordenador para paginar lo o se tendría que hacer una consulta, traer todos los objetos y volcar lo  en otra lista ya ordenada para después solicitarlo paginado?
Gracias es simplemente una duda.
se que en Android existe el método distanceTo existe algo en javascript que sea igual??
Un ejemplo es walapod tu entras y te salen primero los 20 primeros artículos ordenados por cercanía.

Si consulto desde Madrid y me salen  los items ordenados de mas cerca a mas lejos.

Si consulto desde Barcelona y me salen los items ordenados de mas cerca a mas lejos
teniendo esta colención

```
    {
    "_id": "5ee74a38c3ba249508a8c014",
    "index": 0,
    "name": "bici 1",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": -36.167271,
    "longitude": 30.045611
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a3822b1e1b8dfbb86bc",
    "index": 1,
    "name": "bici 2",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": 88.416006,
    "longitude": -49.909889
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38f5a372da4f52bba1",
    "index": 2,
    "name": "46189e93-74f8-4c1a-9fac-9ed1e4228175",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": 83.427032,
    "longitude": 2.615932
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38f9e7f101da8a8df0",
    "index": 3,
    "name": "bici 3",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": -16.717524,
    "longitude": 38.962426
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38dc519af5f867fe8e",
    "index": 4,
    "name": "bici 4,
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": -7.242124,
    "longitude": 96.967712
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a38089ab586ae9219cb",
    "index": 5,
    "name": "bici 5",
    "isActive": false,
    "latitude": -2.478039,
    "longitude": 15.451835
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ee74a384052a686fa06b845",
    "index": 6,
    "name": "bici 6",
    "isActive": true,
    "latitude": 23.08468,
    "longitude": -109.18014
  }
```

Teniendo esa colección, la pregunta es ??
Hay alguna forma de solicitar los datos por cercania ??
Tendria que primero transformar los datos de las coodenadas y crear una nueva colección con la distancia hasta mi posición y hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin crear una nueva colección con la distancia,
Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia por este detalle `sea mongo o sea SQL o la que sea`, se específico.

Comment: no creo que sea demasiado amplia, pregunto como se podria hacer y cual seria mejor de hecho la consulta no es exactamente sobre la base de datos si no de como hacerlo, con una colección que se vaya modificando con la distancia o con alguna  serntencia expecifica de sql que no la conozco o alguna forma en javascript que tampoco ....

Comment: para mongodb hay un tutorial en la [documentación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/). mySQL soporta [tipos de datos geométricos/espaciales](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html) y PostgreSQL via [postgis](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

Comment: Teniendo la colección que dices tener (asumo MongoDB), no existe forma escribir una consulta sencilla que te devuelva los datos por cercanía. Al menos en MongoDB, los datos Geoespaciales deben ser almacenados de acuerdo a un esquema particular, bien sea como [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-geojson) o como [Par de coordenadas heredado](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-legacy), adicionalmente se deben crear los [índices](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-indexes) geoespaciales adecuados. Saludos

Comment: Si no lo tienes así en tu colección te tocará realizar una serie de complejas tareas para ubicar los elementos cercanos a algún punto (latitud y longitud) dado, y deberás buscar algún algoritmo que haga este ordenamiento por ti.

Comment: En el caso de SQL Server, los datos también deben tener una estructura y un tipo definido para poder realizar una consulta SQL que te devuelva los datos ordenados por cercanía. Puedes consultar la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) para que tengas la idea del tipo de datos y estructuras necesarias. Si no dispones de los datos en dicha forma, igualmente tendrás que realizar una serie de procesos para obtener el resultado esperado a partir de los datos que te devuelva tu consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Todo dependerá de la forma en que estructures tus datos, para sencillez opta por SQL, para mas programación MongoDB.

Vamos a considerar que tienes los datos de esta forma:

```
{
    "location": {
       "type": "MultiPoint",
       "coordinates": [
          [ -73.90, 4.03 ],
          [ -13.98, 40.68 ],
          [ -3.37, 4.48 ],
          [ -7.14, 40.76 ]
       ]
    }
}
db.geo.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
               -3.97,
               40.77
            ]
        },
        "spherical": true,
        "distanceField": "distance"
    }}
])
```

Entonces la siguiente petición nos devolverá la situación de la localización respecto al grupo de coordenadas antes mencionadas:

```
{
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        -73.90, 4.03
                ]
        },
        "distance" : 824.83 
}
{
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        -13.98, 40.68
                ]
        },
        "distance" : 1114.06
}
{
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        -3.37, 4.48
                ]
        },
        "distance" : 3266.47
}
{
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        -7.14, 40.76
                ]
        },
        "distance" : 3351.90
}
{
   $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
         type : "Point",
         coordinates : [ <longitude>, <latitude> ]
      },
      $minDistance: <distance in meters>,
      $maxDistance: <distance in meters>
   }
 }
```

Ahora, sabiendo la distancia respecto al punto seleccionado puedes en el servidor colocarlos de cercano a lejano.

Otra forma de solucionarlo es crear figuras geométricas con las posiciones y posicionar en función de punto dado, con `$geoWithin`.

Visita estos enlaces para mas información:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/
[perticiones geolocalición MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/)